# Postman Mock with Path Variables

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

So I have successfully setup a postman mock server and can leverage the simple GETs that do not have any path variables in the api url but ALL the GETs that are something like `{{url}}/users/:urserId` or something like `{{url}}/users/:userId/favorits` are responding with `mockRequestNotFoundError`

just trying to figure out the correct way to get this working with the path variables

[image]

Comment: What is `:urserId`? perhaps it needs to be `urserId`

Comment: @Div, so with postman to define a path var you identify the var with ':' so by adding :userId it will plug in the value given in the path variable (i added a screenshot). you suggestion might work but then i would not be able to have the userid as a var. thanks for the thought tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify the value of :userId in the uri:

Let's say you have a value : 10, your uri for mocking would become `{{url}}/users/10/favorits`